# Stop repeatedly auto-associating accounts on login!

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-page, login, linked-accounts

I want my Meta profile kept *un*associated with the others.  Maybe that's swimming against the current, but that's what I want.

***Feature:*** Don't automatically associate my account when I login.

Auto-associating when I create a new account is fine: I only have to rejigger the associations once per new account.  But I run a development branch of Chrome, and if I have to kill it often (like I have today), then I often lose all my cookies, which means I get logged out.  This also applies to anyone that uses multiple computers, possibly public ones.

This is primarily an issue of what I want shown on my profile page: I don't want someone viewing my SO profile to click-through to my Meta profile.  I want to keep the two somewhat separate, because I don't want the Unicorny aspect of Meta to color my more-professional/-serious profiles.

I don't want to eliminate this fun aspect from Meta, either, even though I've participated in it less often lately. I want to freely switch avatars (and maybe even display names, my current is 28 days old) and participate in [[friday]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/~friday~) posts without having to worry what they may automatically be linked with.

Comment: I was prolly 3/4 of the way through that last conversation 'fore I realized who you were on A51. [Someone needs to keep track of this stuff...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/26518#26518)

Comment: @Shog9: A good point, but that's also why I put my SO profile URL as my homepage on the Meta profile.  (And other users have varying display names.)  I will use the workaround Jeff suggests if I must, in any case.

Comment: I completely agree with Gnome. It is really annoying.

Answer (score -7):

To do this, you must use a different OpenID for your meta account.

Comment: If this is the final answer, go ahead and tag [status-declined] and I'll go figure out the swapping process. :(

Comment: -1 this is really annoying. I want to keep my meta profile separate..

Comment: If one has some website to which one could add OpenID headers, then one should be able to "fool" the sites into thinking one is somebody else, [while still using the same actual OpenID provider](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51711/openids-are-wrongly-identified/51713#51713).

Comment: I would down-vote this answer as well if I could. This is death by 1001 paper-cuts. Someone as brainy as yourself could surely come up with a state machine that keeps the users happy. Why auto-associate the accounts at all? Why not let the users opt-in rather than opt-out?