# Should Meta allow anonymous questions?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, asking-questions, meta, unregistered-users

You can normally ask anonymously on any (all other?) SE sites by just posting a question.

However, Meta says:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> - name and email, or your OpenID, are missing

(And what's the "name and email" doing there? You can't enter them.)

Comment: While I don't agree with the author, it's certainly a legitimate question.

Comment: @Lance: However, I strenuously object to willfully abusing the system of migrating questions.  Had this been asked on Meta correctly (and probably tagged [discussion]), I get the impression it wouldn't have been treated so harshly.

Comment: @The, I'm sure you're right about that.

Comment: FWIW, I did search for a dupe before cleaning up the question, but couldn't find one.

Comment: (-1) for willfully spamming StackOverflow when they are clearly aware of Meta.

Answer (score 10):

Meta is a place for discussing the Stack Exchange network. The people best suited to the manner of discussion that occurs are the active community that participate in the network. So it naturally follows that there is a level of feature that restricts participation in talking about the network, to those who actually are a part of it.

Registration is fairly simplistic. If you want to really voice your opinion about Stack Exchange, then you should make it known that you actually care about the community. And if you cannot be bothered to actually register, then it says lengths about how little you *actually* care about being part of the community. And there's no real benefit to discussion the community with someone who (apparently) doesn't even care how the community ends up.

Comment: Anonymity still has its place.  For example, what if a diamond moderator or someone even more officially connected wanted to post without their position coloring the discussion? (For better or worse, Meta is used for discussion.)

Comment: @TheCat Going by [Jeff's answer to one of your questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52272/stop-repeatedly-auto-associating-accounts-on-login/52280#52280), I wouldn't be surprised if the staff might have spare OpenIDs to use for such situations. Perhaps anonymity does have its uses, but I wouldn't be surprised if this reasoning is fairly close to the official rationale for restricting posting on Meta.

Comment: I've seen it suggested that sock puppets can be legitimate separate profiles on SO (as long as you *don't* abuse them for vote fraud), such as answering vs asking; doing the same on Meta isn't far off.  So yes, you can participate anonymously that way.  Hell, on the internet you don't know if I'm really a [cat](http://idolizeyourkillers.com/wp//2009/12/ontheinternethro.jpg) in the [first place](http://www.unc.edu/depts/jomc/academics/dri/idog.html).

Comment: @TheCat I know you're not a cat because you're actually a gnome.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you just register? It's not hard.

Comment: (-1) The user is *aware* of registration, and they are specifically asking why they are **forced** to for Meta.

Comment: Sometimes users run into problems registering, and this rule means they are unable to ask why they can't register.

Comment: Sonic is referring specifically to me. See:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355965/cannot-create-a-login-from-email-link and also : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356013/unable-to-obtain-help-on-registering-an-account-without-registering-an-account?noredirect=1#comment1189800_356013