# Don't automatically associate accounts unless the account is new

Tags: feature-request, association

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop repeatedly auto-associating accounts on login!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52272/stop-repeatedly-auto-associating-accounts-on-login)

Every now and again I get logged out of SO and when I log back in again, it automatically associates accounts again. Given that I only want certain accounts associated, I have to keep  fiddling around every time it logs me out (Which has happened twice today)

If we have to automatically associate accounts, could we do it only when the account is first created?

Comment: I agree that it should be associated automatically only once...