# How do I stop people seeing my associated account on other Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, linked-accounts

I have tried to un-associate all my account.

However the next time I log into any site I get.

> “n” accounts automatically been
>   associated

I wish to use a single OpenID for ease, however I don’t wish someone to be able to find me on a none work related site from my profile on a work related site.  This is just not good for my “personal branding”.

I have set up some Stack Exchange sites to use a 2nd email address and my nick name. This shorts out the Gravatar, but does not stop Stack Exchange from trying to associate all of my accounts.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52272/stop-repeatedly-auto-associating-accounts-on-login

Comment: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58573/associate-account-based-on-confirmed-email-not-openid

Answer (score -2):

Due to auto-association rules, this is no longer possible unless you use two different OpenIDs.

Comment: Please explain the point of OpenId if I need to have many different OpenId accounts…

Comment: Evan after I have added a new openid to my account on a server exchange site, it is not claer how to remove the other OpenId

Comment: How difficult would it be to simply have a boolean 'hidden' associated with each associations, which won't show it on the public page? It will still be associated, but won't show. And it won't auto-associate, since it's already associated.

Comment: @Roe, that would be a **lot** better then nothing but will not let you associate good of sites, e.g. DIY with Gardening and Stackoverflow with Serverfault

Comment: @Ian; well it would. Since the bools would be associated with each site (warning: overuse of the word 'associate') ;) so DIY would hide all by Gardening and SO would hide DIY and Garderning, and so on. It'd take some work, but I guess most people don't care if they're associated, so they won't be bothered.