# Associate account based on confirmed email not OpenId

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, linked-accounts

I wish to keep some stack exchange account separated from others, having (and using) more than one OpenId is a pain.   However I already have more than one email address that I use to control gravatars etc.

Therefore please associate accounts based on confirmed email address.

If the account does not have a confirmed email address then the opened could be used as now.  For most users there will be no change, as the “starting” email address is provided by the OpenId provider most of the time.

see also: [Stop repeatedly auto-associating accounts on login!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52272/stop-repeatedly-auto-associating-accounts-on-login)

Answer (score 1):

I don't like this idea. It's better to 'fix' the auto-association, rather then start using emails back and forth. I agree with you that it's somewhat abusing the OpenID concept to automatically associate all accounts everywhere, but I think there are better solutions to that problem than to work around OpenID althogether.

Comment: Given that email is allready used to control the gravatar and I wish to associate account in the same "grouping" as I used my different gravatar's for, I thought email would create the least work for the **user**.