# Can I have accounts on different SE sites that are not linked?

Tags: support, user-accounts, linked-accounts

I would like to register on other SE sites, without having the accounts publicly linked in my profile (different user names would be nice for that, too). Is this possible?

Potential use-case: Assuming I want to prove my skills to a future employer by showing that I have answered many questions in the related field, they don't need to see that I am spending all my spare time playing D&D.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179007/what-are-the-possible-alternatives-to-maintain-separate-accounts-for-the-workpl http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58566/how-do-i-stop-people-seeing-my-associated-account-on-other-stack-exchange-sites

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't unlink the connections between your accounts on different SE sites, this is not supported by SE at all. I've posted [a feature request to allow users to hide the connection between accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197600/allow-users-to-hide-connections-between-accounts), but that hasn't been implemented and I doubt it will be implemented in the near future.

You could theoretically create a completely separate account with a different Email and using a different OpenID provider, and only use that account on specific sites. This is not against the rules, but there are some things you have to be careful about.

There are some mechanisms that can trigger account merges, for example logging into a second account while being logged into your first one. You have to avoid those mechanisms, to be sure I'd use an entirely different browser for the second account.

You account also must not interact at all, but if you don't use them on the same site this should be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it you can do this but would need a different email address for them.  Not only this the accounts must never interact with each other.  I.E. no upvoting yourself or answering your own questions or you run the risk of the accounts being merged. You could also trip yourself up and get merged based on browser cookies etc. That said I think it is frown upon to have multiple accounts anyway.

Comment: They mean they want to have an account on Parenting and one on Gaming, but not have them show up as belonging to the same

Comment: In theory, our guidelines permit multiple accounts as long as they don't interact, as you say.  But it's *very* challenging to avoid auto-merging.  Over time, it's pretty likely the cookies would result in them being merged.

Comment: @random I know exactly what he is saying he wants.  To do that he would need to have seperate accounts would he not?  Mad Scientist says more or less the same as I have (albeit with a bit more detail)  and gets upvoted for it twice yet I get down voted .  Go Figure!! Some people are so padantic lol

Comment: A user on Cooking cannot upvote a post on Android, but you have written this answer as one Skeptics account interacting with another Skeptics account

Comment: And as an account on SE you can use that account to access many parts of it.  There is nothing to stop one account meeting the other so it is down to the user to prevent this from happening. I am sure there are many other trigger that will merge acounts but to keep it from happening you need to be aware of all of them do you not?