# Better management of associated accounts

Tags: feature-request, linked-accounts

Correct me if I'm wrong but I cannot be able to clear association of a particular without clearing all associations. If there is a way to do it, it doesn't seem to be very clear. For instance, an obvious way to do it is when the user hovers over the block which links to the user's other SE account, a little "x" could be displayed at one of the corners. Pressing the "x" would clear association with *that* account.

Comment: Why would you want to deassociate accounts?

Comment: related: [Stop repeatedly auto-associating accounts on login!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52272/stop-repeatedly-auto-associating-accounts-on-login)

Comment: @Lord.Quackstar: For whatever reason one wants to. For example, when one of the SE accounts hits 200+ reps and you want +100 on another SE account you associated earlier.

Comment: but you just need to log out and in again to have all accounts automatically re-associated after clearing all associations, at least to date

Comment: I didn't know that for one.