# Allow choosing which part of the profile shall be synchronized

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, profile-sync

Updates to some information should be sync-able without destroying previously individualized per-site details.

As an example, consider changing your location or homepage, while you want to keep your [meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) or [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) display name and description different from the one you use at [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) (say, for making the first few google-hits of yourself less hobby-related), or you may want to mention your favorite programming languages on your SO description while on [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com), it'll rather be your favorite dishes...

Therefore I suggest putting a symbol (e.g. **⎘**) next to profile entries that are out-of-sync and can be synchronized individually by clicking on that symbol.

Example:

> [image: Example (feel free to edit in a freehand-circle)]

Comment: `you want to keep your meta.SO or Arqade display name and description different from the one you use at SO` why would you want to do that? Seems like it would confuse people. Just curious.

Comment: @JimmyPena One reason would be that I'd prefer someone googling me finding my http://physics.stackexchange.com account without a too direct connection to [some Arqade questions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/14249/88) of me. I don't want to hide that either, therefore no separate account, but the first internet-impression should maybe be a bit more serious. Other possibilities include linking to your company's homepage at SO while at meta.SO you may link to your personal blog etc...

Comment: Re confusion, my gravatar is the same everywhere and my accounts are linked, so _should_ there be a reason to directly associate my SO posts to my Arqade ones (just one example), that is the least amount of logical deduction I expect from someone having come up with said reason ;-)

Comment: Related: [Allow "Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts" to exclude selected sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137933)

Comment: Related: [Choose information when copying profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66380)

Comment: I don't consider the second one a duplicate since it sounds like this request is approaching the problem from the opposite end, if I've read correctly.

Comment: @TimStone Thanks for mentioning these, I have already upvoted the second one in the past. Although now that you mention it, my suggestion looks very similar except that I suggest showing a button directly next to an entry that is not globally equal in order to propagate that change globally, instead of the there mentioned checkboxes.

Comment: @Tim But since you mention opposite end, a second symbol (e.g. ⎗) could indicate the possibility to copy information over from the entry that is used across most profiles, or open a popup that allows to choose from which site with a different entry one wants to copy. But I'd say that's a new feature-request then.

Comment: I think I understand now. You want to change your location across all sites, but not overwrite the per-site information you've changed (ex: display name). How about a series of checkboxes next to each field, then a button at the bottom that says "Save and copy checked fields to all Stack Exchange accounts"?

Comment: @JimmyPena that's what [Choose information when copying profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66380) suggests. It's also a good idea that I support, but that would require two clicks (or five, depending on what the default checkmarks are) to perform instead of one...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Choose information when copying profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66380/choose-information-when-copying-profile)