# Change profile picture for all SE accounts

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, profile-picture

[We now have the ability to upload a profile image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161083/172011) without using [Gravatar](http://gravatar.com). I like that.

But I would like to change my profile picture on ALL SE accounts using that new method. Currently I have to open all my profiles seperately and upload the image manually. I don't even have the ability to choose an already uploaded image from another SE account.

Can we please have a button like: *Save image to all Stack Exchange Accounts* like we have one  for other profile information?

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81750/allow-users-to-set-the-base-profile-that-your-stackexchange-com-profile-inheri) for a feature-request to fix the problem with the current method.

Answer (score 3):

[As mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149436/disable-gravatar-on-stack-overflow?lq=1#comment467709_161083) in the comments on the answer you linked to,

> ...the Save and copy profile to all Stack Exchange profiles will work to sync all avatar images network wide just as it does currently for the About Me section.

So, you can simply sync your profile data network wide using the existing button, and your uploaded image will come with it.

Comment: I've tried this. It doesn't work for the self-uploaded avatars.

Comment: Using this method will override all individual profile info in other accounts

Comment: @Mysticial Works for me, [meta-tag:status-norepo].

Comment: Then lemme try it again. I last tested this when the feature was first rolled out.

Comment: Oh you're right. It does work now. I guess I tried when they were still tinkering with the new feature.

Comment: @juergend Well, true. In that case this would just be a more specific implementation of [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142153/allow-choosing-which-part-of-the-profile-shall-be-synchronized), I suppose.

Comment: @Tim, it isn't working, I gave it a day to sync pictures and it still hasn't done it.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Syncing with the network profile is [seemingly a separate issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163818/support-non-gravatar-avatars-on-stackexchange-com-global-profile), but the button does indeed work for syncing across per-site accounts.

Comment: @TimStone, no, I just checked Super-User and it doesn't sync there either, also Webapps.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Hmm, not sure what to tell you then. I tested it after Mystical's comment and clicking the "Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts" button when editing my profile pushed the image out to my other accounts no problem (and then selecting my Gravatar and doing the same switched them back).

Comment: @TimStone, I've been clicking on " Sync with oldest profile (Stack Overflow)." a bunch in my network profile, and it says it synced, but hasn't.  My "about" hasn't synced either.

Comment: @LanceRoberts That's a different button that just syncs your network profile, but doesn't copy data across per-site accounts. And that (per the above link) doesn't seem to take your non-Gravatar image at the moment.

Comment: @TimStone, so where is the button you're talking about?

Comment: @LanceRoberts At the bottom of [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/13295), which is rather unintuitive for this use case.

Comment: @TimStone, thanks, that did the trick.