# Allow "About Me" to sync only to subset of sites

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

I'm active on [several StackExchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/users/1019257/m0nhawk?tab=accounts) and it's hard to manage the "About Me" section.

I'm thinking of some page where user can sync not all, but some sites and showing all "About Me" on one page.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66380/choose-information-when-copying-profile

Comment: I thought the About Mes were already synched now.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: There is now only option to sync **all** about me's.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a "Copy profile to sister sites" button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16640/add-a-copy-profile-to-sister-sites-button)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards - it's not a duplicate as this is asking for control over which sites the "about me" gets copied to, not all of them.