# Can I change my username on all sites keeping the profile information intact?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, profile-page

Suppose I have 20 accounts on SE platform.

I have different *About me* description on the them. I want to take the decision to change my username on all accounts, but keeping my current description on each site.

Currently this is possible only by opening all each profile, clicking *edit*, editing the username and clicking <kbd>Save profile</kbd> button.

If I click <kbd>Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts</kbd> button the profile description will be overwritten on all sites. I don't want such a thing to happen.

So, how can I change *only the username* on all sites, keeping the current profile information intact?

Comment: I would say that this is included in [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66380/205508), but not really a duplicate.