# I cannot change my username because I have images in the description

Tags: discussion, reputation, profile-page, privileges

Consider the following story:

User Alice has a Stack Overflow account having a good reputation. When Alice creates a new account on another site from SE platform she will get 101 points of reputation because of association bonus (that is 100).

On Stack Overflow Alice has images in profile description. On the new account the Stack Overflow profile will be cloned having the same images.

In the new account Alice opens a bounty of 100 points and award the points to Bob. Alice remains with 1 point of reputation.

Now the problem: Alice wants to change her username. She changes her username in the textbox and clicks **Save Profile** button. She will get the following error:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>
> - we're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images in their profiles. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images.

---

Is really Alice a new user not to be able to post image in her profile just because she awarded a bounty of 100 points to Bob?

Is this a good reason for what Alice will have to change her profile description?

Why until changing her username was Alice allowed to have images in her profile description even she had only 1 point of reputation?

I do not agree with this...

Comment: While I agree with the general idea, if bounty won't be taken into account for privileges it will make things really complicated and very confusing. I prefer to implement a warning once you set a bounty "setting this bounty will revoke your privilege "X/Y/Z" are you sure?" in the final step.

Comment: Anyway there is simple workaround for your specific case: change the username on other site where you have more than 10 rep and click "Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts". I did it recently to bypass the 30-days limit and it's a well known and valid way.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That will [override my profile descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213739/205508)! :-) And yes, a warning would be useful.

Comment: True, but one can't eat the cake and leave it whole. :D

Comment: There's another solution: don't award a bounty large enough to drop you back down to 1 reputation. Or you could just go answer another question. Seriously, it's 10 reputation. Building in extra checks so that you can't lose that particular privilege just isn't worthwhile.

Comment: If you like the idea of a warning, see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11930/152859).

Comment: I'd forbid setting bounties that put you below 101 rep. 10000 free reputation from association bonus is already silly, being able to distribute that free rep as bounty is even worse.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for the `Save and Copy...` tip. Much appreciated. Saves me the wait until 22 Jan. It's been like putting on a Halloween Mask and finding out that Theatrical Glue persists for 30 days...

Comment: @BillWoodger lol, can't agree more!