# Are Stack Exchange accounts automatically linked?

Tags: discussion, linked-accounts

If I open an account on a second Stack Exchange site with the same email address as my Stack Overflow account, will they automatically be linked?

If so, how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a second SE account will automatically be associated with your SO account, and there is no way to avoid this.

You can hide linked accounts, as explained in [Hiding sites from the main StackExchange.com profile page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267121/hiding-sites-from-the-main-stackexchange-com-profile-page).

Comment: Thanks. Will this last, or will the automatic association continue occurring?

Comment: Not sure, but judging by this question, it seems it will continue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52272/

Comment: Does this happen instantly? I just registered an account at Area 51, and had to manually "add" my email again somewhere in the profile before it linked. I registered with an email that was already linked to about 6 accounts.

Comment: Pretty sure the ability to clear associations was removed quite some time ago.

Comment: @ale true, better edit this answer to prevent confusion.