# Can I quit my association with ONE of the Stack Exchange specific sites?

Tags: support, association

I got associated to many Stack Exchange communities and I want to clean up sites I don't use. How can I stop being associated with, for example, Mathematics Stack Exchange but not the others? I have signed up with my Google account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can delete that account using the instructions mentioned in [How do I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account) in the Help Center. This will delete it only on one site and won't affect your accounts on other sites.

Alternatively, you can hide one of your accounts without deleting it—see [Hiding sites from the main StackExchange.com profile page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267121/310998).