# How do I hide my accounts on a specific Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, hidden-communities

Can I hide **my accounts** that I already participate in, for a specific site?

For example, I'm in one where I don't want to make my accounts visible for others:

[image]

Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you can hide as many of your accounts from ordinary members as you wish.

If you go to **[Edit Profile & Settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current)** on any of your sites, you will see the button **[Hide Communities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/hidecommunities/current)**, 2nd last option as in the example below:

> [image]

There you can select which communities you want hidden.

Note that [the hidden communities will still be visible to moderators and Stack Exchange staff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276581). They will show up in your Stack Exchange profile with gray backgrounds. For example, this user has their "3D Printing" site profile marked hidden:

[image]

Comment: I find this interface very awkward. Why can't I also just do this from the Accounts tab of my network profile? It makes no sense to me that the way to control my set of accounts across the network, is from a submenu of a configuration page that's otherwise account-specific.

Comment: Doesn't this change sync to all sites? I thought the question was about hiding specific sites on specific sites.

Comment: Hiding communities like this is a boon. Thanks. If I've asked a question on any community and I don't want to hide the community but want to disassociate my name from the question, is there a way to do it? Will setting a question as "community wiki" achieve it? Basically, for any chosen question I asked long ago, I don't want people to see that Nav asked it. It should be shown as an anonymous user.