# Single profile vs multiple profiles

Tags: support

Is it against SE rules or suggested good practice to have a different profiles for every SE site rather than a single  profile?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ameta.stackexchange.com+are+multiple+accounts+allowed) of [What's the policy about having multiple user accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts).

Comment: Can I ask why you would want this? Network profile is very convenient and as an answer states, will get association bonuses. I understand why someone may want multiple log ins on a single site, I can't see any reason to mange seperate emails and passwords etc for each site you join.

Comment: OK then yes, in general, you can do that but be aware of the consequences so you don't accidentally trip the vote fraud detection. Nothing is stopping you from having as many profiles as you like, on any site.

Comment: Jeff answers this in the dupe: "It is not a problem to have multiple accounts, as long as they aren't voting for each other and doing other sockpuppet-y things." This has not changed over time, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Do you mean different profile texts or actual separate accounts?

Answer (score 4):

Managing more than one login is a utter and complete pain (and I have a second account for a reason, and I only use it at work), and there's no real benefit from it.

Having one per site means separate emails *and* passwords *per* site

If you have a separate account per site, in theory, they won't interact with each other but there's a reason we have a single sign on across the network.

This might also lead to some weirdness *if* you do accidentally create a second account on a site you do already have another account on, especially if you manage to trigger off an automatic account merge.  (It shouldn't happen.) You would also run afowl the rules if you're suspended somewhere and accidentally interact on another account.

Save yourself the pain and make use of the mostly excellent single sign on across the network.

Comment: You didn't really answer the actual question here though. The question is if it's against the rules.

Comment: Well, its not best practice. The dupe covers the rest :D

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - no, the dupe has little to do with my question as well as your answer. Anyway thanks for your effort,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to have separate profiles per site you can do it that way if you really really want to since those profiles won't be able to interact with each other, but there are significant advantages to having a single profile.

- You can benefit from the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus-and-how-does-it-work) on all sites. This means, amongst other things that you start out being able to comment on any site you join.
- You also see all messages in one place e.g. if someone comments on one of your posts, you'll see that message regardless of which site that comment is posted on. Otherwise you'd have to log in separately to each site to see if anyone's asked you for clarification or in fact solved your problem.

You can always [hide your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290092/how-do-i-hide-my-accounts-on-a-specific-stack-exchange-site) on some sites so it's difficult for casual viewers to see that you're active on particular sites if you're worried about your privacy.

Comment: @Gio https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290092/how-do-i-hide-my-accounts-on-a-specific-stack-exchange-site