# Only five communities appear in the displayed list in my profile where there should be 7 (I have 10, of which 3 are hidden)

Tags: support, profile-page

I have joined 10 communities, but only five appear in the displayed list in my profile. If I edit the list of five, I am shown all seven. So why the restriction?

The communities icon at the top right of the title bar also shows just five communities (though not the same ones shown in my profile).

An I missing something here?

In the images below I have set 7 to visible, and 3 to hidden. Only 5 show up as visible.

[image]

[image]

Comment: When I visit [your profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1474510/lee-xp), I don't see anything like the top image in your question.  I only see 1 community listed (MSE), not the 5 that your image shows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with hidden communities, it's just a bad user experience that makes you think you have accounts only in five sites/communities of Stack Exchange, even when you have more.

Expected UX is to show something like "show more", or "5 out of X", etc.

That is the case in the [activity tab of the profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity): (need to scroll down  a bit to see it)

[image: accounts widget in the activity tab of profile showing link to all accounts]

This also showing only the top 5 accounts, sorted by reputation, but also clearly showing there are more.

Comment: Thanks. That's great. Still very odd that you only get shown five of your communities when you get the drop-down by clicking  the far right icon on the title bar where it shows all 183 sites, but only five of your own!

Comment: Yeah, the top bar list got even more requests to change it, and the same bad UX. (Of not telling you trivial detail which is how  many you have, or at least that you have more)

Answer (score 3):

> none of which are set to be hidden

This isn't true. In your network profile, I (as a moderator) see exactly 5 grey communities (including this very site), indicating that they're hidden:

[image]

There are five with a white background, which aren't hidden. These are the ones that show up in your profile.

For how to un-hide, see [How do I hide my accounts on a specific Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290092/323179)

Comment: I had set the five to Hidden subsequently because I wanted to see them in the profile. I have now unhidden 2 of them so there should be 7 in my profile list as unhidden, but there is still only 5.

Comment: @Lee-xp And now I see 7 in your network account that aren't hidden. Are you just saying that you see 5 with a "View all N accounts"/"See all" link in your site profiles? That's how it's supposed to work since some people have too many communities to fit elegantly on the page.

Comment: OK that answers my question. Thank you. Is there a way I can modify the question so that the downvotes will stop? - please. Or maybe you could delete the question?

Comment: @Lee-xp I think the edit you just made helped a lot.

Comment: MIght it be possible to edit your answer to reflect the reworded question?

Comment: "Are you just saying that you see 5 with a "View all N accounts"/"See all" link in your site profiles?" - The View-all link only appears on other people's profiles, not my own. Is there a way to get links to all my communities - especially the ones that don't appear in the limited lists in in my profile? - I would ask this as a separate question, but all the downvotes have freaked me a little.

Comment: @Lee-xp: Re *"downvotes have freaked me a little"*: Yeah, that is unfortunate. It goes all the way back to [Atwood not wanting to spend ***any more time than absolutely necessary*** on a meta site](https://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/). It was nearly overturned during [the 2019 crisis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336526/stack-overflow-is-doing-me-ongoing-harm-its-time-to-fix-it).